# How can I extract the upper triangle of a symmetrical matrix in R, excluding the diagonal values (all the 0s)

Tags: r, extract, triangular

it feels to me like this question should have been answered before but I couldn't find it anywhere. How can I extract the upper triangle of a symmetrical matrix in R? I want to calculate the mean of such a matrix, but without the 0s in the diagonal, since they will tint my results.
I have this code:

```
library(Matrix)
matrix <- as.matrix(distObject)
m[lower.tri(m)] <- 0
triu(m)
```

Currently this gets me:

```
          V2        V3        V4        V5        V6        V7
V2 0.0000000 0.4946237 0.6834532 0.6653992 0.6881029 0.6438849
V3         . 0.0000000 0.7183673 0.6531532 0.6959707 0.6458333
V4         .         . 0.0000000 0.4024896 0.6845238 0.7075472
V5         .         .         . 0.0000000 0.6901840 0.6843854
V6         .         .         .           0.0000000 0.3821429
V7         .         .         .         .         . 0.0000000
```

However, I need something like:

```
          V3        V4        V5        V6        V7
V3 0.4946237 0.6834532 0.6653992 0.6881029 0.6438849
V4         . 0.7183673 0.6531532 0.6959707 0.6458333
V5         .         . 0.4024896 0.6845238 0.7075472
V6         .         .         . 0.6901840 0.6843854
V7         .         .                   . 0.3821429
```

Would be great if someone would be able to help!

Comment: after the `lower.tri` call maybe add `m <- m[-nrow(m),-1]` but really need a reproducible example

Comment: Wow, that worked perfectely! Thank you!

Comment: Rereading your question, if you "*want to calculate the mean of such a matrix, but without the 0s in the diagonal*" is `mean(m[upper.tri(m, diag=FALSE)])` enough (and this is the same as `mean(distObject)`? i.e. without the sparse matrix stuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @user20650 I found this code that does exactly what I want:

```
library(Matrix)
m <- as.matrix(distObject)
m[lower.tri(m)] <- 0
m <- m[-nrow(m),-1]
triu(m)
```